# Jquery/Javascript | HTML Table Sum Total Records of sibling TD in last TD

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am Trying to Update the Last  based on the sum of sibling  in that row..

The Table TD has class `contenteditable = "TRUE"` when clicked.

so i am trying when someone try to update the digit on that td column it should also update the last  in that row.

Here is the Fiddle of the Table i have now..

**[JS FIDDLE LINK HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/yhjw23of/1/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add [keyup() event](http://api.jquery.com/keyup) for `.inner class` like,

```
$('tr.tableRow td.inner').on('keyup',function(){
    $tr=$(this).closest('tr');
    var sum=0;
    $tr.find('td.inner:not(.total)').each(function(){
        sum += Number($(this).text());
    });
    $tr.find('.total').text(sum);
});
```

Also in my demo I added a class `.total` to show the total of all inner class. See the **[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/yhjw23of/8/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate on blur of edited TD

```
$('tr.tableRow td.inner').on('blur',function(e){

    var sumTD =  $(this).parent().find("td:last");
    sumTD.text(parseInt(sumTD.text())+ parseInt($(this).text()));

        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yhjw23of/9/

Answer (score 0):

check your js fiddle link

```
 $('tr.tableRow td.inner').on('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();

            $(this).attr('contentEditable','true');
            $(this).addClass('inputCopyCat');
            $(this).focus();
        });
        $('tr.tableRow td.inner').focusout(function(e){
            $('td.inputCopyCat').removeAttr('contentEditable');
            $('td.inputCopyCat').removeClass('inputCopyCat');

            var currentTableRow = $(this).parent();
            var currentTabelRowSum = 0;

            currentTableRow.find('td.inner:not(:last)').each(function() {
                var userInput = parseInt(this.innerText);

                if(!isNaN(userInput)) {
                    currentTabelRowSum += parseInt(this.innerText);
                }
            });

            currentTableRow.find('td.inner:last').text(currentTabelRowSum);

        });
```

Comment: JS FIDDLE checked your link. last column not showing the sum.